# Qt creator: loading up a project file located in subdirectory

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

a legacy project I am working on has the following folder hierarchy:

```
src
|--- folder1
|--- folder2
|--- Buildfiles
    |--- my_app.pro
    |--- components
        |--- comp1.pro
        |--- comp2.pro
```

The pro file that builds the project is my_app.pro, which has (among other things) these lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH = folder1 folder2
include(components/comp1.pro)
include(components/comp2.pro)
```

If I run qmake from the src directory: `qmake Buildfiles/my_app.pro` the project builds cleanly.
If I now try to use Qt Creator to open the my_app.pro file, it's not loading any headers or sources (in folder1 and folder2) since (I assume) Qt Creator will look in the current
directory for folder1 and folder2 and it cannot find them. It does load the components/compX.pro though.

Is there a way to make Qt Creator load up the pro file correctly without changing the pro file itself (as there is client code building it from the src directory)?
By perhaps writing a new short pro file which will load the my_app.pro file?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If changing the my_app.pro file is not an option, you can add a subdirs.pro file in your root folder, which would simply contain the relative paths to all the subdirectories mentioned as arguments to the 'SUBDIRS +=' qmake system variable. This should work well.

For reference- https://wiki.qt.io/SUBDIRS_-_handling_dependencies

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that doesn't work. It seems that when Qt Creator parses the Buildfiles/my_app.pro it still can't find folder1 and folder2 as it assumes that the paths are relative to the Buildfiles directory.

Comment: Use the $$PWD qmake system variable, to specify the path relative to it.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete solution based on the folder hierarchy I've given above? Thank you